# In JAVA what is meaning of System.in get wrapped in BufferReader object?

Tags: java, java-io

I'm reading Herbert Schildt book for Java in input-output portion of Java there's written that:

> wrap `System.in` in a `BufferedReader` object

What's meaning of this object technically?

Comment: It does just what it says. It creates a *buffered reader [stream]* over another *input stream*: `new BufferedReader(System.in)`. This should be shown in example code. The buffered reader "wraps" the System.in object - think of wrapping paper over a present - which is taken as a dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BufferedReader object is an object that uses a buffer memory for input operations.
Wrapping here refers to essentially using the BufferedReader object to handle the input operations rather than directly dealing with the InputStream. This increases the speed and simplicity of the code as we have to deal with chunks of data rather than individual bytes.
BufferedReader does not work on its own, under the hood it needs an InputStream to work on the lower levels, that's why the BufferedReader is wrapped around System.in stream.

Answer (score 0):

`BufferedReader` wraps around another `InputStream` to read data in chunks rather than reading `byte` by `byte`. In this case `System.in` is the `InputStream` (the standard input by default).